# Unable to set a default serialized array using dbdelta()

Tags: database, mysql, dbdelta

I am trying to set up  a table with `dbDelta()` and one of the columns will have as default a serialized array with predefined values. The issue here is that `dbDelta()` explodes the query using semicolons to separate the queries. Is there any workaround for this? The charset I'm using for said column is `utf8_bin`.

```php
$sql ="CREATE TABLE my_table_name (
    Id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    serialized_data varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a:7:{i:0;b:1;i:1;b:1;i:2;b:1;i:3;b:1;i:4;b:1;i:5;b:1;i:6;b:1;}',
    PRIMARY KEY  (Id)  );"

dbDelta($sql);
```

I've already tried using `\x3B` instead of the character itself, but it is still parsed as a semicolon before being exploded so it doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/204053/edit) and paste in the relevant code (in this case, your `dbDelta()` call and the context to go with it).

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the problem is a result of the explode on semi-colons. We can use the [`dbdelta_queries`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/dbdelta_queries/) filter to fix it.

In this solution we're assuming that all queries start with CREATE, INSERT or UPDATE. If you have queries you're running through dbDelta where this isn't the case, the `preg_match` line will need adjusting or it won't work correctly.

```
add_filter( 'dbdelta_queries', 'my_dbDelta_queries' );

function my_dbDelta_queries( $queries ) {

    $toJoin = array();
    $start  = array();
    $count  = 0;
        foreach( $queries as $i => $query ) :
                if ( !preg_match( "/CREATE|INSERT|UPDATE( [^ ]*)/", $query ) ) :
                        if( !empty( $start ) ) :
                            $toJoin[$count] = array( $start[key( $start )] );
                            unset( $queries[key( $start )] );
                        endif;
                    $toJoin[$count][] = $query;
                    unset( $queries[$i] );
                    $start = array();
                else :
                    $start = array( $i => $query );
                    $count++;
                endif;
        endforeach;

        if( !empty( $toJoin ) ) :
                foreach( $toJoin as $join ) :
                    $queries[] = implode( ';', $join );
                endforeach;
        endif;
    return $queries;

}
```